# If first child is iframe

Tags: jquery, parent-child, prepend, nodename

I am trying to find out if the first child of one div is an iframe and if so, prepend it to another div.  I am doing something very similar with images but they are easier to locate in that they will always be inside of the first `p` element.  This is what is what I have that is throwing a `children[0] is undefined` error.

```
     $(".post").each(function() {

    if($(this).find(".post-excerpt").children[0].nodeName.has('iframe').length){

            $(this).prepend("<div class='featured-video'></div>");

            $(this).find(".post-excerpt").children[0].nodeName.has('iframe').prependTo($(this).find(".featured-video"));
    }
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<article class="post twelve columns centered">
    <header class="post-header">
        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
    </header>
    <section class="post-excerpt">
        <iframe height="166" src="http://something.com"></iframe>
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Actually, the first answer here worked perfectly but it was deleted.  `if($(this).find(".post-excerpt :first-child").is('iframe'))`.  Not sure why it was deleted but it works just fine.  I believe I was over thinking it.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
$('section.post-excerpt').each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    var $firstChild = $el.children().first();

    if ($firstChild.prop('tagName') == 'IFRAME') {
        alert('It is an iframe');
    }
});
```

Here, I made a JSFiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/uGAqY/

Comment: @undefined - No real use for caching the intermediate objects here.  This could also be: `if ($(this).children().first().prop('tagName') == 'IFRAME') {...}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `first-child` selector:

```
$(".post").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).find(".post-excerpt iframe:first-child").length ) {
       // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).find(".post-excerpt")` is jQuery object, and as jQuery object it has `children` function, not property

here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5emu/2/)

```
$(".post").each(function () {
    var firstChild = $(this).find(".post-excerpt").children().get(0)

    if (firstChild && firstChild.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'iframe'){
        var container = $("<div class='featured-video'></div>")
        container.prepend(firstChild);
        container.prependTo(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where did you find a jQuery `.children()` method that takes a numeric argument?  I don't see that in the jQuery doc.  `.children()` takes a selector argument.